# OS X-like deadkeys behavior on Linux

Tags: osx, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm on Debian (actually Crunchbang), and my notebook has a default US layout keyboard.

My native language is Brazilian Portuguese (pt-BR), so I've changed my layout with `setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl`. This allows me to use deadkeys to produce (Maçã, é,...), but it makes it harder to type commands like `cd ~/download` (I have to type `cd`, `~[space]/...`).

Mac OS X with "US-Int" layout has a different behavior. You press "~", it shows "~" on the screen and moves the cursor to the right. If the following character is "a", instead of showing "~a", it shows "ã".

Is it possible to enable this "mac-like" behavior on Linux? How?

Comment: old question, but you might try the `altgr-intl` variant of the `us` layout.  it moves the deadkeys to level3, so pressing `~` prints `~`, and `AltGr+~` gets the deadkey.  not quite the behavior asked for, but may be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to say that the [comment from quixotic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110187/os-x-like-deadkeys-behavior-on-linux/574361#comment741503_110187) works perfectly on Gnome3, namely:

> you might try the altgr-intl variant of the US layout. It moves the deadkeys to level3, so pressing ~ prints ~, and AltGr+~ gets the deadkey. Not quite the behavior asked for, but may be good enough.